# How to align div elements while using css tables

Tags: html, css

I need to align my `div` elements such that the first column element takes up two rows and the second column elements occupy the first and the second row,and are stacked one below the other using css tables.

My html

```
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="core.css"></head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="specialsticky">
    <img src="Hydrangeas.jpg" alt="first image">  
  </div>

  <div class="specialsticky">
    <img src="Chrysanthemum.jpg" alt="second image"> 
  </div>

  <div class="specialsticky">
    <img src="Desert.jpg" alt="third image">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the css part

```
#wrapper {
display:table;
width:1024px;}

div.specialsticky:nth-child(1){
display: table-cell; border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: middle;
width:604px;height:447px;}

div.specialsticky:nth-child(1) img{
width: 604px;height:447px;}

div.specialsticky:nth-child(2){
display: table-cell; }

div.specialsticky:nth-child(2) img{ width: 424px;height:222px;}

div.specialsticky:nth-child(3){display: table-cell;}

div.specialsticky:nth-child(3) img{width: 424px;height:222px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the divs are contained in the wrapper, you could remove `display: table-cell` on the two small divs so they naturally collapse underneath each other but inline with the larger div.

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/vinil/1/edit)

CSS

```
#wrapper {
display:table;
width:1024px;
font-size: 0; /* fix inline gap */
margin: 0 auto;
}

div.specialsticky:nth-child(1) {
display:table-cell;
border:1px solid #000;
vertical-align:middle;
width:604px;
height:447px;
}

div.specialsticky:nth-child(1) img {
width:604px;
height:447px;
}

div.specialsticky:nth-child(2) img,div.specialsticky:nth-child(3) img {
width:424px;
height:222px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using floats? Apply the class float:left on the first and second div. 
After the first and second div you need to clear the floats add the following:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

The last table should align left, if not also add the float:left class to it as well.

Comment: I can't use the `clear:both` property since my actual program is using loops to generate the three ` div ` elements.So I can't add html code after a particular `div` element.That is why I am using css table property to display them